# Writing custom filter in flask-assets (webassets)

Tags: python, flask, flask-assets, webassets

Using Flask with flask-assets (from webassets) I wrote my own custom filter for a css compressor, [following the documentation](https://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_filters.html). It doesn't seem to work:

```
from csscompressor import compress
from flask_assets import Bundle
from webassets.filter import Filter, register_filter

class NoopFilter(Filter):
    name = 'csscompressor'
    print("noopfilter")

    def output(self, _in, out, **kwargs):
        print("output")

    def input(self, _in, out, **kwargs):
        print("input")

register_filter(NoopFilter)

bundles = {
    'home_css': Bundle(
        'css/main.css',
        'css/forms.css',
        output='gen/home.css',
        filters='csscompressor'
    )
```

The class is called twice on startup and the filter is found by it's name, but `input()` or `output()` seem never to be called. The css file is created, but obviously without any compression. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a caching issue. Changing the filter name made it work. Hopefully, this helps someone pulling their hair out over a few kB.

Answer (score 0):

An example of compressing the CSS using the csscompressor package (pip install csscompressor)

```
from csscompressor import compress
from flask_assets import Bundle
from webassets.filter import Filter, register_filter

class NoopFilter(Filter):
    name = 'css_compress'

    def output(self, _in, out, **kwargs):
        css = compress(_in.read())
        out.write(css)

    def input(self, _in, out, **kwargs):
        css = compress(_in.read())
        out.write(css)


register_filter(NoopFilter)


bundles = {
    'app_css': Bundle(
        'css/responsive.css',
        'css/ads.css',
         filters='css_compress',
         output='all/app.css'
    ),
```